# How to compare two rows of JSON values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a billing data stored in a table like this in SQL. I want to compare BillContent (Json Value with unknown properties). My goal is to compare current version's BillContent from previous version to see what changes have been made by different departments. As a result, I would like to see the changed value. What would be the easiest way to get this done in SQL?

|  | ID | BillID | VersionNo | BillContent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | 9 | 1 | {"ID":9,"Description":"testing Bill","Active":true,"AddressID":14,"DepartmentID":9,"LogbillingInfo":true,"ForwardBill":true,"VIP":false,"BillingBranchSectors":[{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":0,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}],"BillingVersions":[]} |
| 2 | 151 | 9 | 2 | {"ID":9,"Description":"testing Bill","Active":true,"AddressID":14,"DepartmentID":9,"LogbillingInfo":true,"ForwardBill":true,"VIP":false,"BillingBranchSectors":[{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":0,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}],"BillingVersions":[]} |
| 3 | 152 | 9 | 3 | {"ID":9,"Description":"testing Billagain","Active":true,"AddressID":14,"DepartmentID":9,"LogbillingInfo":true,"CancellingBillingInfo":false,"ForwardBill":true,"VIP":false,"BillingBranchSectors":[{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":0,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}],"BillingMetaData[]":,"BillingVersions":[]} |

First I used this statement to get the table above:

```
select bvt.*
from BillVersionTable bvt
where BillID = 9
enter code here
```

The output of a desired solution could be just getting the difference between two Json like a table below:

**Possible Output 1:** This output returns the json with only properties that are different or changed in comparing version from original version

|  | Difference |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"Description":"testing","LogbillingInfo":false,"ForwardBill":false,"VIP":false} |

**Possible Output 2:** This output returns a VersionNo and each property of a json as a column for all versions of a given process. NOTE: some of the properties have nested arrays.

|  | VersionNo | ID | Description | Active | AddressID | DepartmentID | LogbillingInfo | ForwardBill | VIP | BillingBranchSectors | BillingMetaData | BillingVersions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | testing Bill | true | 14 | 9 | true | true | false | [{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":0,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}] | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 9 | testing Bill | true | 14 | 9 | true | true | false | [{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":0,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}] | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 3 | 9 | testing Billagain | true | 14 | 9 | true | false | true | [{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":2,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}] | ["metaDatasteps": true, DescriptiveDetail:[]] | NULL |

**Possible Solution:** The simplest way to compare these bill versions is by using SQL built-in JSON_VALUE as suggested by YuTing below. This will return each property of a BillContent (JSON) from version table as a column for all the versions of a given bill id. This is a great solution for the cases where the properties of JSON object are known.
However, JSON_VALUE does not work for arrays as we have some properties like 'BillingVersions' in our JOSN containing arrays. That’s where JSON_QUERY comes.
The example of this approach for bill id 9 is as follows:

```
    select bv.VersionNo,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.ID') AS ID,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.Description') AS Description,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.Active') AS Active,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.AddressID') AS AddressID,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.DepartmentID') AS DepartmentID,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.LogbillingInfo') AS LogbillingInfo,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.CancellingBillingInfo') AS CancellingBillingInfo,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.ForwardBill') AS ForwardBill,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.VIP') AS VIP,
JSON_QUERY(BillContent, '$.BillingBranchSectors') AS BillingBranchSectors,
JSON_QUERY(BillContent, '$.BillingVersions') AS BillingVersions,
JSON_QUERY(BillContent, '$.BillingMetaData') AS BillingMetaData
from BillVersionTable bv
where BillID = 9
```

Comment: Looks like you want a third party tool kind of [Compare_JsonObject](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/sql-server-json-diff-checking-for-differences-between-json-documents/)

Comment: I am quite new to dealing with json in sql but I have tried the built-in SQL Lag function which isn't much of a help for a case where you have to compare a lot of rows with huge amount of jsons.

Comment: Thank you @Serg. Actually, it was quite hard for me to understand this Compare JsonObject helper function as I am not a SQL expert yet. Thus, I am thinking if it could be done with some built-in SQL function or by a bit of easier approach?

Comment: The simplest comparison is just to compare the whole strings. It will detect the text was changed in a way, including just white spaces like `"ID":9,` to `"ID" :  9,` . Not sure this is what you want.

Comment: Do you need to know exactly what was changed, or do you need to just know it's different. Please post an example of what output you want to see when comparing version 2 and 3. SQL Is not the best tool for unstructured data (JSON) or text comparisons but it can do it. This is a complex requirement and the _Compare_JSON object_ article referenced actually serves it up to you on a plate. I'm afraid you're going to have to dig in to that article and understand it bit by bit. There are no shortcuts here and this is actually a great learning opportunity.

Comment: To give you a helping hand on that article, first you need to go to the bit of code that starts with `CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION` at the end of the article. Run that inside SSMS. That creates a table valued function. What's that? google it, read, and try and absorb it. Then run th ebit of code that starts with `DECLARE @SourceJSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{` and try and understand what is going on

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you so much for your input. Yes, that is very true and yes, I need to know exactly what has been changed? I just thought maybe SQL has the ability to do the JSON comparison by some easy to apply built-in functions.

Comment: When you say you need to know exatly what has been changed, can you edit your question and show how you want that represented. Because for example it might be changed somewhere in the middle and somewhere at the end so do you want to see just those changed bits returned? As lareday mentioned, this is much better managed by tools that have been doing this forever (called a diif tool). There are many toosl that have been around for a long time that do it well. Can you edit your question and provied some background - who is viewing this information, why do they want it, what do they need to see?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I edited the question a bit as per your suggestion. Thank you so much for your help. I think that this thread would be super helpful for the next person. I am going to understand and build that CompareObject helper function as explained in the article.

Comment: No offence but _The output of a desired solution could be just getting the difference between two Json._ does not actually tell us anything. What specific chunk of text or tabular format would you expect to see as the output when comparing version 2 and 3? If you don't know, then you're not really ready to ask a question about it

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I added the expected results in my question. I hope that makes things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [json_value](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), check the document from microsoft.

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    BillID int NOT NULL,
    VersionNo int NOT NULL,
    BillContent nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL,
);
```

```
insert into data values
 (150, 9, 1, '{"ID":9,"Description":"testing Bill","Active":true,"AddressID":14,"DepartmentID":9,"LogbillingInfo":true,"ForwardBill":true,"VIP":false,"BillingBranchSectors":[{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":0,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}],"BillingVersions":[]}')
,(151, 9, 2, '{"ID":9,"Description":"testing Bill","Active":true,"AddressID":14,"DepartmentID":9,"LogbillingInfo":true,"ForwardBill":true,"VIP":false,"BillingBranchSectors":[{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":0,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}],"BillingVersions":[]}')
,(152, 9, 3, '{"ID":9,"Description":"testing Billagain","Active":true,"AddressID":14,"DepartmentID":9,"LogbillingInfo":true,"CancellingBillingInfo":false,"ForwardBill":true,"VIP":false,"BillingBranchSectors":[{"SectorID":9,"InspectorID":0,"BillingMovingSteps":[]}],"BillingMetaData":[],"BillingVersions":[]}')
```

```
select 
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.ID') AS ID,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.Description') AS Description,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.Active') AS Active,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.AddressID') AS AddressID,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.DepartmentID') AS DepartmentID,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.LogbillingInfo') AS LogbillingInfo,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.CancellingBillingInfo') AS CancellingBillingInfo,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.ForwardBill') AS ForwardBill,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.VIP') AS VIP,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.BillingBranchSectors') AS BillingBranchSectors,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.BillingVersions') AS BillingVersions,
JSON_VALUE(BillContent, '$.BillingMetaData') AS BillingMetaData
from data
where BillID = 9
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c31ee1e028b88e54a6055db37a069de6)

Comment: OP complaints BillContent is a "Json Value with unknown properties"

Comment: @YuTing Thank you so much for the answer. This works partially for me as Json value has unknown properties. It is a really good solution if you know all the json properties.